# PHP base64 encoding custom alphabet

Tags: php

I try to use base64_encode() and base64_decode() but with custom alphabet. Default alphabet is:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
```

say I want to use:

```
"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210+/"
```

found a class on internet but doesn't work as expected. Any idea on how to achieve this as simple as possible?

Comment: Take a look at this class - it might work: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#78765

Comment: Did you tried to modify the class you found? And could you tell us where is it?

Comment: Removed the comment, my mistake

Comment: Yes h2ooooooo, that is the class I used. Problem is it acts funny: normal base64_encode() gives me say for string "test": dGVzdA== and with that class (same alphabet) gives me: dGVzdAAA, I need to be identical (with same alphabet, I can change it).

Comment: @xtmtrx did you include the padding character in the custom alphabet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of other 100 questions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ultra easy, [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) can do this out of the box:

```
$default = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
$custom  = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210+/";

$encoded = strtr(base64_encode($input), $default, $custom);
```

Comment: Thought about that but I'm not sure if it achieves valid base64 output?

Comment: @xtmtrx: I 'm not sure what your intent is here. If you want valid base64 encoding, don't touch the output of `base64_encode`.

Comment: Using "my alphabed" above ("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210+/") the encoded string should give me "wTEawZ==" but with the class in h2ooooooo 's example gives me "wTEawZZZ"

Comment: @xtmtrx: I really hope you are not using this as "encryption".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the custom encoding defined above, to decode with a custom alphabet, you can do the following:

```
    $custom = 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210+/';
    $default = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
    $decoded = base64_decode(strtr($input, $custom, $default));
```